# Objective C Find a HTML input line in NSData

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am trying to read in a website and find a input line from the code. But can't figure out how to find the a line of data. 
Trying to find the line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="01234abcABC">
```

Here is my code.

```
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mywebsite.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: &error];
if(data == nil)
    return;
// Need to loop through the data line by line to find this line?
```

Comment: Looking for this line: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="01234abcABC"> in the data.

Comment: Convert `data` to `NSString` first, with `initWithData:encoding:`. Then it's a simple `rangeOfString:`?. For the rest, you may want to use `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection` (and async calls).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be your best friends.

```
// Add a NUL byte so that the data is a valid C string
NSMutableData *mutableData = [data mutableCopy];
char nul = '\0';
[mutableData appendBytes:&nul length:1];

// Wrap the data as a string
NSString *dataStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes];

// Find the target string within the data string
NSRange inputTagRange = [dataStr rangeOfString:
    @"<input\\s+type=\"hidden\"\\s+name=\"_token\"\\s+value=\"[0-9a-zA-Z]+\">"
    options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

// Expand the target range to cover each line that the target spans
NSRange inputTagLineRange = [dataStr lineRangeForRange:inputTagRange];
```

See it working [here](https://ideone.com/oPGonv).